# Web application using Hibernate+MySql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

i was asked to do a book manager at university with hibernate and mysql. I have a simple question. If i choose to do a web application, grails already uses hibernate. GORM runns over hibernate. so to use mysql i only need to configure jdbc grails drivers and that's it?

i mean, "for the project you must use hibernate and mysql" - this are the requirements. So can i do that way?

thanks in advance,
JM

Comment: Just curious - what's a "book manager"?  What kind of scale are we talking about here?  Is this homework, or a management system for the school's library?

Comment: It's a management system for the school's library - middle complexity. My doubt is about hibernate. I didn't understand exactly what he does.I mean he is an intermediate to link my DB to my grails project?

Comment: My doubt would be writing an application for such a large audience that a real customer had to depend on when I had so little experience.  Are you being paid or graded for this?

Comment: sorry my bad, i explained myself the wrong way. This small-meddium project is for a course in my university - to show what i have learned. There will be no people depending on it because it is just for academic purposes. I understand your point and i apreciate your concern :x thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course you can.

You'll need to get the MySQL JDBC driver from [this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) location.

Grails?  When you're new to programming?  Whose idea was this?

Personally, I think that taking on all these unknowns is risky for someone who's "new to programming."  Do you know anything about SQL or JDBC?  Have you ever written a web project before?  This could be difficult.

I don't know how to be more specific.  Download the JDBC JAR from the link I gave you.

I'd recommend that you start with a [JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) tutorial first.  Hibernate is not for you - yet.

Hibernate is an object-relational mapping tool (ORM).  It's a technology that lets you associate information in relational database tables to objects in your middle tier.  So if you have a PERSON table with columns id, first, and last Hibernate will let you associate those data with the private data members in your Person Java class.

That sounds easy, but it gets complicated quickly.  Your relational and object models might have one-to-many and many-to-many relationships; Hibernate can help with those.  Lazy loading, caching, etc. can be managed by Hibernate.

But it comes at a cost.  And it can be difficult if you aren't familiar with it.

If you have a deadline, I'd recommend creating a Java POJO interface for your persistence classes and doing the first implementation using JDBC.  If you want to swap it out for Hibernate later on you can do it without affecting clients, but you'll have a chance of making progress without Hibernate that way.

Comment: You're way better off using Ivy - the default BuildConfig.groovy has a commented-out declaration for the MySQL driver as its example - just uncomment that. This way you just have one jar file in your Ivy cache instead of identical jars in every project that uses it. It's a little dated so the version should be bumped to the latest.

Comment: im thanks for the fast answer. im kinda new to programming world, can you be more specific please?

Comment: I would not recommend Ivy to someone that's new to programming.

Comment: hm right i understand your point. Answering your questions, i have about 5 months to do it, but as i'll be having more than that project to do, i would say i will have like 15h/week durint 5 months. The problem is, i have to use hibernate and sql - it is mandatory.

Comment: If you've used Grails/Gorm, you were using Hibernate and SQL underneath.  If you already know those, what's different about your book management app?  Your question is as vague as they come.  I'll vote to close it.

Comment: w/e. when you do an application with grails/gorn you use Hibernate in a transparent way. I got my anwer and im pleased with it - @accepted